# Saving Biometric data to SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, biometrics

I have an upcoming project which requires the recording of thumbprint / fingerprint scans in a database (currently proposed as SQL Server). Now I have a few questions I need to explore:

- How does SQL Server handle the embedding of images? Is it better to embed the scanned images in the database or to embed the path and store the images in a folder? My concern is the number of files could eventually reach 7 million and the data would need to be queried.
- What software or otherwise would I need to be able to "read" a thumbprint / fingerprint image and compare it to all records in the database for duplication?

Comment: What are you asking? Clueless on databases? Because "biometric" information without any more information (what form, how do you think you can identify duplicity) is extremely rare. This way I would say "hire someone with a clue" - mostly someone very experiened in .NET development but mostly someone who has worked with this kind of data before.

Comment: @TomTom edited my question

Comment: Yeah. google is your friend. Or the SEARCH HERE. The first question has been answered to many times it is not funny. The second one is off topic here - we do not recommend products or services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up [Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363040/An-Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-for-Absolute-B) as an easy-to-learn framework in C# that lets you work with databases nearly seamlessly.

**EDIT**
Ok, with the update to the question, it is easier to answer. For the first part. I would store the images on disk, and save the path to the image in the database. This is considered a good approach.

For the part of software used to read fingerprints, you should search a little around for examples. There are tons of examples, but they all vary with the type of fingerprint reader that you aim to use.

Comment: What kind of biometrics should be irrelevant. If it's fingerprint, blood pressure, pulse, or anything, as long as you can represent them with a value, you can store them to the database. I thought you were asking about how to store data to a database? The KIND of data that you're storing is irrelevant in this question.

Comment: @PedroGDias edited my question